# CAN Bus - unable to read from

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, can-bus

I am working on a device with two CAN bus interfaces based on two different board groups and I'm implementing an API to open/close/read/write.
I am using Linux sockets for this implementation. Most of what I have implemented is based off of this link: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html

I have been able to open a socket for each CAN bus and I am able to verify that I am writing (via return value from write() and a can analyzer) but I am not getting any response from the sockets in return.

Would I need to have different threads to handle each socket?

See my can socket info from ifconfig, note the "RUNNING" is not in can1, does that make any difference?

```
can0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
      UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
      RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:10
      RX bytes:8 (8.0 B)  TX bytes:1928 (1.8 KiB)
      Interrupt:142

can1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10
          RX bytes:16 (16.0 B)  TX bytes:528 (528.0 B)
          Interrupt:143

        fd_set set;
```

and my read function:

```
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(canbus->fd, &set);

struct can_frame frame = {0};

struct timeval timeout;
if (wait_time_ms > 0)
{
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = wait_time_ms * US_IN_MSEC;
}

int bytes_rd = select(canbus->fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
//int bytes_rd = read(fd, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
if (bytes_rd < 0)
{
    log_lvl(LOG_ERR, "can read error");
    rc = LIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT;
}
else if (bytes_rd == 0)
{
    //timeout
    log_lvl(LOG_ERR, "timeout");
    rc = LIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT;
}
else
{
    int test = read(canbus->fd, &frame, sizeof(struct can_frame));
    log_lvl(LOG_ERR, "%02x %d", frame.can_id, test);
    // frame.data[8] is where the data is being stored
    // load the can msg into the buffer - assumes that the message is the size of the buffer
    memcpy(buffer, frame.data, size);
    rc = LIB_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Using the CAN Bus analyzer I was able to manually send some frames back to my code. So I'm digging into other issues of why there isn't a response from the boards when sent a message.

Comment: A couple of things to check first of all: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251).